# Saltstack: How to define in top.sls "Package less than version ..."

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following issue:

I use salt stack to manage my minions, which are running in different datacenters. But the package repositories are not consistent: Not all have the latest versions of salt. With Salt stack I can of course work around that, so I added to the top.sls:

```
'not G@saltversion:3003.1':  
  - fixes.saltversion
```

But I don't like that up there. I've tried several variants, but couldn't manage to select minions which have a specific grain less than a specific version. Like in this case: To select all minions which have an older version than *3003.1* to apply a state on them, that gets the package directly from a different repo.

**How do I select "less than" of a Grain?**

I've googled around already and didn't find anything matching my case. The Docs are also not helpful for my case. I've read about custom matcher: But do I really need to implement a custom matcher for that?

Thanks in advance for your help everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following grain: `saltversioninfo`.
This grain is a list: `[ majorversion, patchversion ]`.

You can target minions with releases later than Fluorine (2019.2.0) like this:

```yaml
'P@saltversioninfo:0:\b(?:3[0-9]{2}[0-2])\b or ( G@saltversioninfo:0:3003 and G@saltversioninfo:1:0 ):
  - match: compound
  - fixes.saltversion
```

This compound match will target minions with release between 3000 and 3003.0.

This is a bit static and you need to modify this after a new release. But I hope this will help you.

EDIT:

The matcher above is untested, I don't have minions with older version. You should test the matcher before with the following salt command:

`salt -C 'P@saltversioninfo:0:\b(?:3[0-9]{2}[0-2])\b or ( G@saltversioninfo:0:3003 and G@saltversioninfo:1:0 )' test.ping`

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your quick response! Well, that fulfills my thoughts and fears: This is not a numeric value which can be filtered over operators like "less than" and "greater than". Which is freaking sad :/  
  
I also tried to filter with the `osmajorrelease`(because it's another numeric grain) based on "less than" and "greater than" but no luck.

But I also found out the `test.ping`module is wonderful to test which minions will be selected. :)   
  
My major goal was to simplify the top.sls the Regex doesn't match that, but anyway: Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe I put the more complicated "selections" in a node group, i donno. I think that is not very well implemented from salt stack.

Maybe I will write a self-made matcher which make a string to numbers conversion.  

But at least I didn't overlook something :)

Comment: From the "static" standpoint i wanted to insert the salt masters grain which saltversion he has.

This would have the advantage: the master will be upgraded first, and afterwards the state kicks in and the minions will be upgraded afterwards :)